# What does '<,'> really mean when you enter an Ex command in visual mode in Vim?

Tags: vim

After you visually select a block of text, and type <kbd>:</kbd>, Vim writes `'<,'>` for you.

But I'm curious on what `'<,'>` really means and if it can be edited.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7759455.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `'<,'>` notation is a vim *range* that represents the last selected block. In general, the range boundary specifier `'x` means "whatever mark `x` points to". The special case for `<` and `>` refers to the start and end of the last selected block.

For more information and examples of different kinds of ranges, see the [Range page on the vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Ranges).

Comment: Haha cool, I can actually jump to `'<` and `'>` after I select something and de-select. I'm not sure how useful that would be (since you can just re-select with `gv`), but it definitely helps you understand `'<,'>`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @hobbes3, `'<` and `'>` can be useful in a mapping or in a macro if you want to prepend or append the selection with some new text. See `:help motion.txt` for more mind blowage.

Comment: @romainl Isn't is easier to just type `o`+motion during visual mode to select more text?

Comment: Once you are in select mode yes but when you are doing relatively complex things with or around the selected text you will certainly get out of select mode at one point or another. In such a situation, those marks are more practical and deterministic than constantly do `gvo`. Especially in the context of a macro or a mapping which are not interactive.

Answer (score 3):

[From vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Ranges):

> ...because the command was entered while lines were selected, Vim displays the command as:

```
:'<,'>s/old/new/g
```

> The range '<,'> is entered automatically to identify the lines that were last visually selected (they do not need to be visually selected now