# Vim :'<,'> When entering command mode

Tags: vim, range

Sometimes in vim I appear to be entering a keymap unintentionally when attempting to enter command mode. For instance, when attempting to write `:w` I, sometimes, end up with this:

```
:'<,'>w
```

Which throws the error `E481: No Range Allowed`

It's mostly just a minor annoyance, and I'm more wanting to know what am I doing to initiate the command line in this way with the brackets.

Comment: You are in visual mode. It appears that you accidentally hit 'v' before :.

Comment: ... or you have mouse support and clicked more than one character, causing a visual selection

Comment: Thank you! If you put it into an answer I'll accept :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Vim visual mode, why does the command start with '<,'>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759455/in-vim-visual-mode-why-does-the-command-start-with)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:'<,'>w` appears when you start a command line while being in visual mode. It allows to apply this command on a portion of your document, e.g. to sort some lines. In your case, you have accidentally hit `v` before entering your command.

Comment: This is a feature, not a bug!  `:help v_:`.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to Vincent's correct answer, if you happen to come upon a command that doesn't support a range and gives you the `E481` error (though the given `:write` does support ranges), you can just remove the `'<,'>` prefilled content by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>, and *then* start typing the command. This is quicker than <kbd>Esc</kbd> and re-triggering command-line mode via `:`.